# QGIS Windows Error

Tags: qgis

I have followed [this](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial) tutorial and setted up the QGIS, but while viewing capabilities of just maps, i.e.,
localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
or
localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=c:/myprojects/world.qgs

I am getting error,

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@local.domain and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

But the localhost/ is showing the home page,

[image: For localhost/]

I had research over web and found no solution or results for this!

Can anyone help me to get over this problem, I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The server probably cannot access the project at c:/myprojects/world.qgs

Try moving it to the server directory and try again.